# Codeigniter image name with space upload issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this weird issue about uploading images with name that has space in it.

On normal cases, uploading images goes through the function and there you can somehow remove the space or allow space or do whatever you want.

But in this case, it doesn't. It goes 404 page not found but not on the BASEPATH, it goes 404 on the main directory. 
So I have 2 installations of CI (`/admin` and `frontend` in public_html) where `/admin` directory is inside the frontend.

[image]

Whenever I try to upload an image with name that has spaces, it somehow goes to frontend routes and looks for the /_admin page which is obviously not there thus goes to my custom 404 page.

Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: To temporarily fix my issue, I removed the spaces on my images since it's only a few, lucky me. But I might need a permanent fix for this. JavaScript solution should be my last resort.

Comment: save the file name in DB, and rename the actual file when uploading. When you want to show the file name, get it from DB

Comment: why would you ever want to store files with spaces???

Comment: @AbdullaNilam it would be so easy to do that but the thing is, it doesn't go through the function where it supposed to go. Supposed it should go to `/_admin/products/insert` but the function is now 404 when carrying that $_FILE with spaced name image.

Comment: The above comment should be the way to go, in my perspective. But if you REALLY want to keep your files with a nice name, you must create a function to 'slugify' it; remove unwanted spaces, accented characters and probably any dots in the middle of the filename except, of course, the one that introduces its extension. Then you have to validate if the result filename already exists in the server or not. Note: you can start with some javascript function of course, but you'll need to use PHP nevertheless...

Comment: @Alex have u worked with a REAL client before?

Comment: many. and this still doesn't make sense. if you mean that they will upload files with spaces... well yea, you can never trust user input, but it is your job as a dev to make sure everything is stored in a logical, and standardized manner. hence why the upload lib removes spaces for you by default.

Comment: @Alex eeeek. I know, that's why I posting it here that it's weird that my form doesn't go through the function where I can "STANDARDIZE" my files. please tell me you get it.

Comment: perhaps part of the difficulty i am having in understanding your issue is the general lack of code - form and controller would be helpful as well as anything relevant. remember: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Alex I don't think a code would be necessary. I just have a very simple form with `input type="file"` and a basic controller function (i even added die('test') at the beginning just to test if it's coming in). Nothing really special, everything is working fine if the filename is without space.

Comment: welp, never heard of that one before (or seen it in practice), if I can't test and replicate this scenario I'm not of much help. good luck ;) (shot in the dark, but maybe look into this being a server issue of some sort)

Answer (score 0):

try to use change $config

$config['remove_space'] = TRUE;